# How to update an array which is changed by (and inside) a function so that its updated value(s) can be used in a new function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

How can I make it so that the global array (tallArray) is also updated outside the function?

```
btnregistrer.onclick = function () {
        tallArray.push(inptext.value) ;
        print.innerHTML = " " ;
        for(var tall of tallArray) {
            print.innerHTML += tall + "<br>" ;
        }
        console.log("array " + tallArray) ;
    }
```

Comment: where is the part that you update `tallArray` ? `tallArray.push(inptext.value)` or `tall + "<br>"` ?

Comment: FYI: `print.innerHTML += tall + "<br>" ;` is a very inefficient way to update the DOM. You should build a string and update it once

Comment: What is not updating outside the function in the code above? If `tallArray` is not being updated, than I think you have a different issue. Is the text on the page showing the new content when you set the innerHTML? I have  a feeling this is a case of a submit button submitting the page.

Comment: Your code *does* update the global `tallArray` (by pushing a new element to it). Please show why you think this doesn't work, ideally with the code that wants to use the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Define the array outside your function

```js
var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
function e(){

for(let i=0;i<10;i++)
{
a.push(i);
}
}
e()
console.log(a)
```